# Passing Data to Component in React (props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a Counters components and a Counter components. The Counters class is below and renders four Counter components to a single page and sets their initial value.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import shadows from "@material-ui/core/styles/shadows";
import extendedIcon from "@material-ui/core/styles/shadows";

    class Counters extends Component {
      state = {
        counters: [
          { id: 1, value: 2 },
          { id: 2, value: 0 },
          { id: 3, value: 3 },
          { id: 4, value: 0 },
        ],
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Paper elevation={3} style={{padding: 20, margin:10,  }}>
            {  this.state.counters.map(counters => 
            <Counter key={counters.id} value={counters.value} /> ) }
            </Paper>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Counters;
```

In my Counter class I have the logic and a value of this.props.value

However, the value property is undefined. This worked fine previous to changing it to props.value

Counter class;

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value,
    tags: ["Tag1","Tag2"]
  }



 constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleIncrement = this.handleIncrement.bind(this);
    // handIncrement method needs to be binded to allow for 'this' keyword to have access to 
       it globally.
    //  You can also use the arrow function to bypass the super and binding methods.
  }

  renderTags() {
    if (this.state.tags.length === 0) return <p>There are no tags!</p>;

    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.tags.map(tag => (
          <li key={tag}> {tag} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
    // Gives a key value to each element in the array. React needs to be able to access each element.
  }

  
  //   handleIncrement() {}
  handleIncrement = () => {
    let counterValue = this.props.value
    this.setState({ value: (counterValue += 1) });
    console.log("Clicked")
    console.log(counterValue)
    // In React you need to set the state to update the view(UI). You cannot do it direct i.e this.state.count += 1 as a direct method.
  };

  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.props.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }
  formatCount() {
    return this.props.value === 0 ? "zero" : this.props.value;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* {this.state.tags.length === 0 && "Please create new tags"}
                {/* Render a conditional statement in line - A populated string in JS is 
                 considered truth y, so both values are true */}

        <span
          style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 15 }}
          className={this.getBadgeClasses()}
        >
          {this.formatCount()}
        </span>

        <button
          onClick={this.handleIncrement}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>

        {this.renderTags()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

I created a new let variable and set it to the value of props.value as it was a read only object, however I am struggling to see what the cause is.

I *Think* the reference of props in this Counter class is passing the logic forward to the Counters class to be rendered four times.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please focus on the problem, your struggling story/bad wording on other platforms is unnecessary (Question edited).

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in this snippet:

1. If you using `constructor` ([you shouldn't](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)) you need to initialize the instance with props: `super(props)`.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
  }
```

2. When using `this` in class function you have to bind it to class instance, or just use arrow function (see link above):

```
// should be arrow function
getBadgeClasses = () => {}
formatCount = () => {}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed that. My UI does still not reflect the change in state, though.

Comment: Please create a MINIMAL reproducible example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-xmvnp?file=/counter.jsx @Dennish Vash

Comment: You don't have any logic for changing the parent's (Counters) state, so it will never change. You need to pass a callback to it children.